# Create and Save a Record of a Model on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am currently on the MongoDB and Mongoose section of FreeCodeCamp.

The [exercise](https://beta.freecodecamp.org/en/challenges/mongodb-and-mongoose/create-and-save-a-record-of-a-model) requires the user to create a document instance using the Person constructor you build before. Pass to the constructor an object having the fields name, age, and favoriteFoods. Their types must be conformant to the ones in the Person Schema. Then call the method document.save() on the returned document instance. Pass to it a callback using the Node convention.

I have created the person schema and constructor but I am not too sure about what is still missing and how to piece it all together to implement the solution. Can someone help clarify?

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema({
  name:  {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: Number,
  favoriteFoods:   [String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var joe = new Person({
  name: "Joe",
  age: 24,
  favoriteFoods: ['Apple', 'Banana']
});

joe.save(function(err, persons) {
  if(err){
    console.log("Failed");
  } else {
    console.log("Saved Successful");
    console.log(persons);
  }
});

var createAndSavePerson = function(done) {

  done(null /*, data*/);

};
```

Answer (score 4):

@SQMN has the correct solution. Except that [the FCC prompt](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/apis-and-microservices/mongodb-and-mongoose/create-and-save-a-record-of-a-model) suggests that we first create a new document from the Person model and add data to it, *before* we save it.

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var p = new Person;
p.name = "John";
p.age = 18;
p.favoriteFoods = ["hotpot", "suantangyu"];
var createAndSavePerson = function(done){
  p.save(function(err, data){
    if (err){
      return done(err);
    }
    return done(null, data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the FCC forum user [dnlnav](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/beta-mongoose-challenges-create-and-save-a-record-of-a-model/166524/3), you'll want to move your instance and save function into createAndSavePerson and rewrite the callback passed into save like so:

```
var createAndSavePerson = function(done) {
  var joe = new Person({
    name: "Joe",
    age: 24,
    favoriteFoods: ['Apple', 'Banana']
  });

  joe.save((err, data) => {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    return done(null, data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied about the method you just used. But mongoose have it own method create(obj,callback) which does majority of the work for you. You can use it like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema({
  name:  {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: Number,
  favoriteFoods:   [String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

Person.create({
  name: "Joe",
  age: 24,
  favoriteFoods: ['Apple', 'Banana']
},function(err,result){
    //code to manage error or result if Successful
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a challenge in freeCodeCamp:

- [Create & Save Record](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/apis-and-microservices/mongodb-and-mongoose/create-and-save-a-record-of-a-model)

If you are trying to complete this challenge then please scroll down the template [myApp.js](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/boilerplate-mongomongoose/blob/gomix/myApp.js) file which has proper instructions and function declaration for each step. you will find a empty function with createAndSavePerson(), Please write your logic in that one.

Answer (score -1):

if you stuck by the timeout issues, try to remove `< >` tag inside **MONGO_URI** key or learn [MongoDB basics](https://university.mongodb.com). You'll find out the answer.

Comment: How is this related to OP's question?